# How to stop processing a request in the middle in express?

Tags: node.js, express

My Android app has a 10 sec timeout to wait for a response from the server. If in that time the server hasn't responded yet, it closes the connection and displays an error.

In some edge cases, the server might be stalling for a big computation or a long call to an external service and might be somewhere in the middle of the stack when the client decides not to wait and closes the connection.

In some cases, i'd like to stop the transaction if the user disconnects.

I can add an event listener to `end` event

```
res.on('close', function() {
  // do something
})
```

What can be done from there ?

Comment: Regarding the case of a payment - most such pages have a message along the lines "do not close the browser or refresh the page". I feel so long as there is a warning that they shouldn't close the page you're ok - so long as you can handle whatever they last sent (knowing that they have left) correctly

Comment: What the server should do in such a case entirely depends on the nature of transaction/operation/etc. it was executing at the time the client disconnected. So this question is too broad. You should come up with concrete examples, ideally code snippets, too. As a general guideline, you should implement transactional behaviour with rollback procedures defined for different types of operations.

Comment: @marekful okay, I rephrased the question. 10x

Comment: The client should be able to re-connect , and know ultimate result of such time taking transactions, even after disconnection. Because a connection may be closed to a variety of reason, and not just because client wants to cancel the transaction.

Comment: Output heavy calculations in a child process and stop it in case of disconnection? But in general, there is clearly the smell web sockets, and task queues.